# FFmpeg error: Output file is empty, nothing was encoded

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04

I am using the following command ffmpeg command and execute it in Python. It used to work for at least a month finely. However, its two days it stopped working and generates different errors. The most important one is "Output file is empty, nothing was encoded"

PS: I checked the connectivity to Camera and is healthy. I am able to see the Camera output on my screen using its software.

The Command:

ffmpeg -i rtsp://username:pass@ip_add:port/videoMain -b 1920k -f image2 -r fps -strftime 1 %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg

PS: fps is taken from input. I mainly used 1 for that.

I would be gratfful if anyone can help with this. Thank you.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: https://ufile.io/df3yg

Comment: `[rtsp @ 0x55ae1cbf10e0] decoding for stream 0 failed`

Comment: So what does it mean? How can I get rid of it. It use to work with the same situation perfectly.